# Consulta de data em mysql?

Tags: mysql

Preciso consultar e apresentar os aniversariantes da semana no *dashboard* do sistema, mas hoje um aniversariante não está sendo exibido e gostaria de saber onde está o erro.

Coluna Aniversário: 1970-02-15 (a data está salva deste jeito no bd), tipo date e *nullable*.

Consulta mysql: `SELECT * FROM tbl_usuarios WHERE (WEEK(Aniversario) = WEEK(now()))`

Não tínhamos notado nada de errado, até que o próprio aniversariante nos questionou, agora ficamos na dúvida se o mesmo deve estar acontecendo com outros usuários.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bronca é que a função [`WEEK()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_week.asp) retorna um número entre 0 e 53; de acordo com o ano, o dia pode não estar na mesma semana (ex: em um ano o dia **06/01** está na **semana um**, no outro ele está na **semana dois**).

Uma saída seria adicionar anos a data de nascimento para checar com a data atual (usando o [`DATE_ADD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate)):

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_usuarios 
WHERE (WEEK(DATE_ADD(Aniversario, INTERVAL (YEAR(now()) - YEAR(Aniversario)) YEAR)) = WEEK(now()))
```

Comment: perfeita a explanação, obrigado por contribuir.